Combine likert chart and bar plot ordered by the same order in R using ggplot2
I have a data frame in R produced randomly as you can see in the code section below called df. I want to create two plots using ggplot.The one will be likert chart (horizontal chart) and the other bar chart. but i want to be sorted with the same order. the y axis in the v1 chart must be the same with the v2 y axis chart. In the picture below the y axis has (from top to bottom ) B,A,D,C categories and the v2 has D,C,B,A. I want the categories in the y axis to be matched. How can i do this in R ?

library(tibble)

var_levels <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
likert_levels <- c(
  "Strongly disagree",
  "Disagree",
  "Neither agree nor disagree",
  "Agree",
  "Strongly agree"
)


set.seed(42)
df <- tibble(
  var = sample(var_levels, 50, replace = TRUE),  # Random values from A to D
  val = sample(likert_levels, 50, replace = TRUE)  # Random values from Likert levels
)


df2=df%>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as.factor))%>%
  group_by(var)%>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = var,   # The values in 'var' will become new column names
              values_from = val)%>%
  select(-row)

v1 = ggstats::gglikert(df2)+
  aes(y = reorder(.question,
                  ifelse(
                    .answer %in% c("Strongly disagree", "Disagree"),
                    1, 0),FUN = sum),decreasing=TRUE)



df_total = df%>%
  count(var,val) %>% 
  group_by(var) %>% 
  mutate(pct = round(prop.table(n) * 100, 1)) %>% 
  select(-n) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(val)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = val, values_from = pct)
colnames(df_total) = c("var",likert_levels)
df_total  = df_total%>%
  mutate(order = `Strongly disagree` + Disagree )%>%
  arrange(desc(order))

v2 = df%>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as.factor))%>%
  group_by(var)%>%
  summarise(count=n())%>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = var, y = count)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "lightgrey")+
  coord_flip()


ggarrange(v1,v2,widths = c(6,2))





You have to use the same order for the factor mapped on y in the second plot, e.g. use the same reorder before computing the counts.
Note: I switched x and y to get rid of coord_flip.
library(tidyverse)
library(ggstats)
library(ggpubr)

v2 <- df %>%
  mutate(
    var = reorder(var,
      ifelse(
        val %in% c("Strongly disagree", "Disagree"),
        1, 0
      ),
      FUN = sum
    )
  ) |>
  count(var, name = "count") %>%
  ggplot(., aes(y = var, x = count)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "lightgrey")

ggarrange(v1, v2, widths = c(6, 2))



thank you very much for your answer.Why the legend and the categories are not sorted properly? from left to right it should be strongly disagree disagree neutral agree strongly agree.Not like this.Also the sorting in the if else also does not work.

You convert val to a simple factor without setting the levels. Instead use val = factor(val, levels = likert_levels).

all right.Fixed.Also i noticed that in my real life data set if thec ategories are many (i.e) size of the bars are not equal.The right bar plot ones are bigger and cannot match the others in the left.How can this be fixed?

The most easiest fix would be to switch to patchwork, e.g. try patchwork::wrap_plots(list(v1, v2)). Additionally, to get exactly the same width of the bars you have to ensure to apply the same theme.
